# How can I find object in List with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7

I have a object:

```
public class MyObject 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }     
        public List<MyObject> Items { get; set; }     
    }
```

And I have list of MyObject:

```
List<MyObject> collection = new List<MyObject>();

collection.Add(new MyObject()
{
     Id = 1,
     Items = null 
});

collection.Add(new MyObject()
{
     Id = 2,
     Items = null
});

collection.Add(new MyObject()
{
     Id = 3,
     Items = null
});


List<MyObject> collectionMyObject = new List<MyObject>();

collectionMyObject.Add(new MyObject()
{
     Id = 4,
     Items = collection
});

collectionMyObject.Add(new MyObject()
{
     Id = 5,
     Items = null
});
```

How can I find object with Id = 2 in collectionMyObject with Linq ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are trying to find an object in `collectionMyObject` which has item with id 2, then this should work:

```
MyObject myObject = collectionMyObject.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Items != null && o.Items.Any(io => io.Id == 2));
```

And if you are try to find an inner item with id 2, then this query with `SelectMany` might be helpful:

```
MyObject myObject1 = collectionMyObject.Where(o => o.Items != null).SelectMany(o => o.Items).FirstOrDefault(io => io.Id == 2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I'm a little corrected query and it works Where(s => s.Items != null).SelectMany(o => o.Items).FirstOrDefault(io => io.Id == 2);

Answer (score 9):

```
var item = collectionMyObject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2);
```

EDIT: I misread the question so Andrei's answer looks better than mine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I probably asked the wrong question I had in mind, the search for Items too.

Answer (score 4):

Simple:

```
var obj = collectionMyObject.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way may be:

`(from c in collection where c.Id == 2 select c).ToList;`

It should give a list in return. If want a single entry, then replace `ToList()` with `FirstOrDefault()`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Where` keyword and a lambda like so:

```
MyObject result = collectionMyObject.Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault()
```

Or, to find in the `Items` sub-collection simply do:

```
MyObject result = collectionMyObject.Where(x => x.Item.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault()
```